# How to implement timing-mechanism for fantasy draft process utilizing ASP.NET Core 3.1 SignalR

Tags: c#, programming-practices, web-development, .net, asp.net-core

I have developed a Fantasy Draft system utilizing ASP.NET Core SignalR, along with Azure's SignalR service (for backplane/scaling stuff).

Last year I utilized a poor-mans' javascript version that just polled the database every 5 seconds to check for new "picks" in the draft, or any changes that may have happened in the draft room.

I realized pretty quickly, that version didn't scale very well, hence my conversion to SignalR.

So, the version I use relies on the commissioner of the group to be IN the draft room for the entire duration of the draft. This is necessary because it's the commissioner's connection on the client-side (via javascript intervals) that the "timer-expired auto-pick" fires. As well as when the draft completes, there's a "finalize draft" process that needs to execute.

Surprisingly, I finally had my first instance of where a commissioner left the draft room while it was still going on (I was a member of the group, but NOT the commissioner). Because he left the draft room briefly, and it just so happened that a user timed-out on their pick at the same time, we saw the "current pick timer" go all the to -20 seconds (negative 20).

After that, the commissioner left the draft room right before it completed, therefore that "finalize draft" process never got executed.

My original attempt at trying to fix that last issue was to develop an Azure Function (triggered via timer) to check every X seconds if A) there are any picks assigned to a user that have surpassed their timer and B) check if the draft has completed, and it HASN'T been "finalized".

This would fix both of those scenarios, with a simple Azure Function running in the background...hopefully not tieing up too many resources.

But my question is, is that approach a workable approach, to have a "background process" watching the timers?

Is there a better process to orchestrate the timer mechanism for a draft/bidding process? Are there possibly more issues that will rear-their-head that I'm not thinking of if I continue down the path of the background process/Azure Function timer to handle these timer-expired events?